# Using inherited struct array attributes in ranking an searching

Tags: vespa

I am currently using document inheritance to avoid having to include specific fields in every document type that I make. It works for most scenarios, but when an array of structs is inherited, using that field in ranking and searching seems to break things. For example, take the following application.

```
schema base {
    document base {
        field simple_base type string {
            indexing: summary | index
        }

        struct base_struct {
            field name type string {}
        }

        field complex_base type array<base_struct> {
            indexing: summary
            struct-field name { indexing: attribute }
        }
    }
}
```

```
schema sub {
    document sub inherits base {
        field simple_sub type string {
            indexing: summary | index
        }

        struct sub_struct {
            field name type string {}
        }

        field complex_sub type array<sub_struct> {
            indexing: summary
            struct-field name { indexing: attribute }
        }
    }

    rank-profile default inherits default {
        first-phase {
            expression: nativeRank(simple_sub, complex_sub.name, simple_base, complex_base.name)
        }
    }
}
```

If you try to prepare this application, you will get the error

```
WARNING: invalid rank feature 'nativeRank(simple_sub,complex_sub.name,simple_base,complex_base.name)': The parameter list used for setting up rank feature nativeRank is not valid: Param[3]: Field 'complex_base.name' was not found in the index environment
```

If you take out the `complex_base.name` from the `nativeRank` function, it will compile properly. Additionally if you try to search using the various fields after feeding the following json:

```json
{
  "put": "id:content:sub::0",
  "fields": {
    "simple_base": "simple",
    "simple_sub": "simple",
    "complex_base": [
      {
        "name": "complex"
      }
    ],
    "complex_sub": [
      {
        "name": "complex"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then the following are the results:

```
/search/?query=simple_sub:simple -> 1 result
/search/?query=complex_sub.name:complex -> 1 result
/search/?query=simple_base:simple -> 1 result
/search/?query=complex_base.name:complex -> 0 results
```

If this is the intended behavior then is there a workaround for this other than copy/pasting the
`complex_base` field into every document that needs to inherit it? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to inheritance. Vespa.ai does not support ranking for user defined struct fields. See https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/11580.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll keep that in mind for the ranking portion, but what about the searching aspect of the inheritance? In my example I show that it is possible to search based on a struct field when the struct is within the document itself, but not when it is inherited. It seems inconsistent with searching for non-struct inherited fields since as shown in the above example, I am able to search for the `simple_base` field but not in the `complex_base.name` field.

Comment: It might be that inheritance (Which is just syntax in the document model) is badly integrated with complex structs. If you use &tracelevel=3 you can compare the execution against the backend. I'm guessing that the 0 result is that the complex_base.name is not recognized by the query parsing and you end up searching the default fieldset using 'complex base name complex'.  If this is the case a github issue is welcome, or it's welcome anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into what might be causing it and if it's a parsing issue I will create an issue for it. Thanks for the help!